# How can I create a Regex exp for enter button followed by 4digits in a span tag?

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, autocorrelation

[image]

Referring to above image I need to create a regex expression in JMeter for correlation of the 4 digit number which is dynamically changing.
Can someone help me to create expression for the same?

I tried with \n replacing the enter button in span tag but was not getting the expected results.

Comment: Do you want a LoadRunner solution of just a Jmeter one?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
\r?\n\d{4}
```

This matches a CR?LF (enter) character followed by 4 digits.

Comment: <span id="head_lblMagicno"><strong>




6516
</span>  Could you help in adding the expression in above tag?

Answer (score 0):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I think you should consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor) instead.

The relevant CSS Selector would be something like `span[id=head_lblMagicno]`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)